# Selenium error on OSX when doing Protractor Tutorial

Tags: macos, selenium, protractor, automated-tests

I am trying to get protractor up and running on OSX 10.11.6 by following the guide on [Protractor webpage](http://www.protractortest.org/#/).

here is the setup:

```
$ npm install -g protractor
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
/usr/local/bin/webdriver-manager -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager
/usr/local/bin/protractor -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor
/usr/local/lib
└── protractor@4.0.4 

$ webdriver-manager update
[16:01:00] I/update - chromedriver: file exists /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.22mac32.zip
[16:01:00] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.22mac32.zip
[16:01:00] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.22
[16:01:00] I/update - chromedriver: v2.22 up to date
[16:01:00] I/update - selenium standalone: file exists /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
[16:01:00] I/update - selenium standalone: v2.53.1 up to date

$ webdriver-manager start
[16:01:15] I/start - java -jar /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.22
[16:01:15] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 21540
16:01:16.017 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
Setting system property webdriver.chrome.driver to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.22
16:01:16.042 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.102-b14
16:01:16.042 INFO - OS: Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64
16:01:16.051 INFO - v2.53.1, with Core v2.53.1. Built from revision a36b8b1
16:01:16.097 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform MAC
16:01:16.097 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform MAC
16:01:16.097 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
16:01:16.097 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
16:01:16.099 INFO - Driver class not found: org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
16:01:16.099 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver is not registered
16:01:16.141 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
16:01:16.141 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
16:03:10.472 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chrome}]])
16:03:10.479 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.22.397929 (fb72fb249a903a0b1041ea71eb4c8b3fa0d9be5a) on port 32768
Only local connections are allowed.
16:03:30.725 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'Sebastians-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '10.251.17.130', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:166)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:680)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:571)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'Sebastians-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '10.251.17.130', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:97)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:103)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'Sebastians-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '10.251.17.130', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:138)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The process has not exited yet therefore no result is available ...
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecuteResultHandler.getException(DefaultExecuteResultHandler.java:76)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.checkForError(UnixProcess.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.checkForError(CommandLine.java:185)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:177)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
    ... 19 more
16:03:30.732 WARN - Exception: The process has not exited yet therefore no result is available ...
```

and here I run the test:

```
$ protractor conf.js
[16:03:10] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[16:03:10] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:03:30] E/launcher - The process has not exited yet therefore no result is available ...
[16:03:30] E/launcher - WebDriverError: The process has not exited yet therefore no result is available ...
    at WebDriverError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:26:26)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:639:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:538:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:472:11
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2820:25
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:329:24)
    at Builder.build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:458:24)
    at Hosted.DriverProvider.getNewDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:37:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:190:43)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:264:30
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
[16:03:30] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Here are the files

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js']
}


// spec.js
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('should have a title', function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');

    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');
  });
});
```

I have sat with this issue and searching for days and I really need to get this working.

Comment: How you found any solution to this ? I am also getting this on Win 7